# NSDictionary result type fetch objects in relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdictionary

I was wondering if setting `NSDictionary` reault type, and adding a to relationship would bring up those objects in the results.

Example I have a car object with a toCarparts Relationship.

A carPart object has name, brand, etc. I just want to bring up the carParts.name.

So can I set entity as car and then search the toCarParts and only return the names?

If so how would I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only use *to-one* relationships in in `propertiesToFetch`, e.g.:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Car"];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"name", @"toCarParts.name"]];
```

would work if `toCarParts` is a to-one relationship. It would return dictionaries with the name of the car and the name of the related car part.

It does not work with a *to-many* relationship.

Comment: Would it return just one car part or all?

Comment: It would throw an exception `'Invalid to many relationship in setPropertiesToFetch: (toCarParts.name)'`.

Comment: @MartinR any other option to fetch specific attributes in  one to many relationship ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't fetch only a single property of an entity.

**UPDATE**

Look's like **that's wrong**. Seems it's possible to obtain only some specific attributes using NSDictionaryResultType, check [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/fetchExpressions.html) link out. Maybe your problem could be solved using this.

P.S. Thanks for pushing me to figure this out, I didn't find anything about this in last Marcus Zarra's book.

Comment: Ok, what if I were to fetch the nsdict version of the car object but I wanted it to also fetch the relationship?

Comment: Whew, now I'm not so sure in that, I'll beter remove my answer in a minute. Recently finished reading Marcus Zarra's book about Core Data, looks like I've misunderstood something. Need to review the book again.